# I get this error when refreshing gradle project: Cause: invalid type code: B3

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

After I hit "*Refresh all gradle projects*"

I get the error:

> Cause: invalid type code: B3

I am trying to refresh it because I added this dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

and now want to import OkHttpClient in the class but it isn't working

Java is 12.0.1 Gradle is 5.5

Gradle code:

settings.gradle file:

```
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url  "http://dl.bintray.com/mbuhot/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'mbuhot:eskotlin:0.7.0'
        compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.3.1'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.4'


        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

    }
}
rootProject.name = 'ndmWebApp'
```

build.gradle file:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.3.21'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'ProjectoFinal.ndmWebApp'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    //elasticSearch
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Gradle and Java are you using?

Comment: Could you please add entire code of build.gradle?

Comment: @AndiCover Java is 12.0.1 Gradle is 5.5

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an [open bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9339) with Java 11+, Gradle 5 and IntelliJ.
As far as I have seen it you have two options:

1. Downgrade Gradle to a version below 5.
2. Build your project outside of IntelliJ using the commandline.

This bug is also mentioned [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002683740-Gradle-failure-Java-11-with-Gradle-5-and-Cause-invalid-type-code-CD).